# Error in generating ultimate-seed with yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm attempting to create my first Yeoman webapp using the ultimate-seed-generator. However I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Fidel\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\new-proyect>npm install



> ultimate-seed@0.3.12 preinstall C:\Users\Fidel\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\new-proyect
> node npm-scripts preinstall

npm preinstall script executed
\


> ultimate-seed@0.3.12 postinstall C:\Users\Fidel\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\new-proyect
> node npm-scripts postinstall

npm postinstall script executed
{ [Error: Command failed: cp: invalid option -- n
Try `cp --help' for more information.
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
-
npm ERR! ultimate-seed@0.3.12 postinstall: `node npm-scripts postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ultimate-seed@0.3.12 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ultimate-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node npm-scripts postinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ultimate-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Fidel\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\new-proyect
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fidel\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\new-proyect\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am pretty sure that node js and yeoman were installed ok. I think it can be a problem with Window and yeoman. Anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `post-install` script uses the unix `cp` command to copy files. Being that you're on Windows, that is not going to work

You can run the `npm install` under cygwin or some other unix-type shell on windows.

However, That [package has been deleted from npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ultimate-seed) -- you should try to find one that is up-to-date and use that one instead.

Comment: Ok thanks! @tkone for your answer. But which is the best `MEAN stack generator` for you. You could recommend me the most popular?

Comment: I don't use any code generators so I'm sorry I can't be of much help there. You might try searching [npmjs.org](npmjs.org) for the `yeoman` and `mean` keywords as a start though